# Cauchy's integral formula more then one pole?

Tags: complex-analysis

Cauchy's integral formula says that:
$$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\Gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)}dz$$
Where $\Gamma$ is a closed contour in the positive sense. Does this still hold if $\Gamma$ contains more poles (other then that at $z_0$) of the function $ \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)}$?

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula requires that $f$ is holomorphic, therefore the set poles of $z\mapsto \dfrac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)}$ is $\{z_0\}$.

Comment: I think CIF requires $\;f\;$ to be analytic on $\;Gamma\;$ and on the domain this closed, simple curve encloses.

Answer (score 4):

The version of this for more than one pole inside a contour is called [The Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)